# How to change a color, to another color/transparent, in a BufferedImage with a ColorModel/ColorSpace?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, colors, image-manipulation

**What I'm looking for:**  I am looking for a **very fast** approach to changing all of the pixels of a certain color, in an image, to transparent (maybe another color later, but it should be similar).

---

**What I have now:**

I have a method which scans each pixel of an image for a certain color, and then doesn't write that color in order to create a transparent pixel.

**NOTE:  THE IMAGE WILL HAVE MANY COLORS, IT'S NOT JUST A SINGLE COLOR** (just in case someone has a single colored example).

```
   BufferedImage layer = ImageIO.read(new File(file));
   System.out.println(layer.getWidth());
   BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(layer.getWidth(), layer.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
   WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster();


   int width = layer.getWidth();
   int height = layer.getHeight();

   // Slow method: scan all input (layer) image pixels, plotting only those which are not the transparency color
   int lPixel,red,green,blue;
   for(int w=0;w<width;w++)
     for(int h=0;h<height;h++)
     {
       lPixel = layer.getRGB(w,h); 
       if ((lPixel&0x00FFFFFF) != trans) //transparent color
       {
         red   = (int)((lPixel&0x00FF0000)>>>16); // Red level
         green = (int)((lPixel&0x0000FF00)>>>8);  // Green level
         blue  = (int) (lPixel&0x000000FF);       // Blue level
         // Set the pixel on the output image's raster.
         raster.setPixel(w,h,new int[]{red,green,blue,255});  

       }
     }
```

This method is a slower method than other options out there.

---

**What I've heard could do the job:**

1. I have heard I could be scanning all of the pixels in the int[]  which would be faster than setting each pixel in the WritableRaster, and then setting the color.  I have seen some code examples, and I have a method that I could probably easily implement myself using some bit-shifting of the Alpha element to 0.  I'm assuming the int array being changed directly is just changing it itself, and that's that, but I will have to look it up againt o make sure.

---

2. I also have been reading up on something called the "ColorModel" which apparently defines the data for the image.  I had read that it is responsible for saying that the model has to change RGB data into byte data or whatever so it's possible to mess with the ColorModel to say color x should really display color y....

The problem is...  I cannot find any good examples on "ColorModel"  It seems we should look at one of the subclasses like "IndexColorModel" or whatnot.  I also see "ColorSpace" which seems useful, but at the same time might just be RGB/CMYK/etc....

---

3. I also have heard of "ColorConvertOps" or "LookUpOps" with some examples, but I also read that can be very slow as well...?

---

So I'm curious if someone has an example or something to get me started on the right track with all of this?

It seems that this is a better approach than scanning, since I just need to define 1 color, but even if I had multiple colors, I Would assume it would work the same?

---

So I'm not sure which are the fastest methods, but I need something that will be able to convert many images at runtime, upwards of a thousand+.  One user said he tried running the code above on his 4k screen or a screenshot of it, w/e, and said it took 10 seconds...  Now most images might not be that size, if anywhere close, but it's possible they could be that size, or bigger, so 10 seconds x 1000 images isn't going to go well.......  Granted I'm not 100% sure the size, as it varies.

Any advice is appreciated, thanks a lot!

Comment: If you want to keep the colors of your original image, "scanning all of the pixels in the int[] might be the best way"

Comment: As for the IndexedColorModel, if your original image is not IndexedColorModel, you will need color quantization which is somewhat slow and may produce low quality image.

Comment: Thanks...  So there's no way to change just 1 color in the image itself?  It seemed like that it was possible....

 I saw an example that took a BufferedImage, created a color model of black, and with each MouseEvent would change the ColorModel to where the mouse was based on x coordinates, and would return an "IndexedColorModel" that would change the color from Black to White..



Thoughts?  Thanks for the help thus far!

Comment: Hmm If you think that's the best way...  There is no other way?

I looked up "Color Quantization, " and I see what you mean...  So the "ColorModel"; is a bad idea?  IT seems you can get 24-bit color in the models when looking at the model from an importanted image, but I had an issue created an IndexedColorModel that was more than 16-bits, so I think that's what you were talking about???


Hmmm..... I got excited when I thought this could be much simpler by just changing the data with how colors are represented.  Is it true that the colors are converted, and that's the purpose of the cmodel?

Comment: It could become a very lengthy topic. I have a question though: what are you going to do with the BufferedImage after you set one or more colors transparent? Are you going to same them to some image formats?

Comment: Depends on the instance.  In one instance they are saved to a ".PNG" format, in another instance I want to use them as the BufferedImage itself.

Comment: I still would like to know why a ColorModel wouldn't fully work?  Was it wrong what I heard about the ColorModel allowing a change of one color to another, or is it specific to single colors and whatnot?

Maybe the ColorSpace is the issue?